# Docker and Selenium Grid Error. Error forwarding the new session Empty pool

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid

Today I faced the issue with Selenium Grid while using Docker. I tried to configured it locally and faced one issue, and, unfortunately, I can't find rootcause for it.

When I try to run simple test locally I get this error all the time

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: LINUX, version:  }
```

Full stack trace here https://pastebin.com/YvJKyN32

Then I just tried to download codebase from the first tutorial I found, https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/selenium/selenium-docker-example/

But I had the same error. Then I tried to run on different laptop and it worked. 
Tried docker reinstallation - didn't help.

Any ideas on this? 
Non-working env: Mac OS Mojave
Working env: Mac Os Catalina